# dynamically adding a property name to a typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I have a constant:

```
const name = 'some/property';
```

I'd like to define an interface that uses name as a key for a property in a similar way to using it in an object declaration like so:

```
{[name]: 'Bob'}
```

I tried the following, but it seems that this is doing something else:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [name]: string;
}
```

is dynamically defining property names supported in typescript?

Answer (score 22):

You have to specify the type of **name**. There's no way to use it in an object declaration but you can use the [ ] to set and access the property value.

```js
interface MyInterface {
  [name: string]: string;
}
const n = 'qweq';

let x: MyInterface = {
  'a': 'b'
}

x[n] = 'a';
```

And access it this way.

```
x[n]
```

Check it out in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20n%20%3D%20'qweq'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'a'%3A%20'b'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ax%5Bn%5D%20%3D%20'a'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(x%5Bn%5D)%3B).

Comment: This doesn't work (or maybe my question is unclear). In your example, `x.coolname` is `undefined`.

Comment: You are right that was creating a property with the name n on the X object. I have updated my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, but that is bypassing the typechecking completely, doing this will not enforce object of type `MyInterface` to have a `qweg` property

Comment: that's not very dynamic though. From what I know you can't define a type that allows an object to have any string as a key while at the same time enforcing a specific key name. The first includes the 2nd one.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with Mapped Types introduced in TypeScript 2.1:

```
const name = 'some/property';
type MyInterface = {
    [prop in typeof name]: string;
};
```

This forces all object of type `MyInterface` to have a property named `'some/property'`.

---

I guess this answer is too late for you, but hopefully it can help others. I found this question early on in my own searches for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: This helped! I had a related problem where I wanted a specific (dynamically-given) property inside of a type to have another given type, and ended up with
```type PropertyType<K extends string | number, T> = {
 [P in K]: T;
};

const lala: PropertyType<'test', number> = {
 test: 1,
};```